# Javascript/TypeScript: How to run code directly after the return statement in the same scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

First of all: Is it possible? I have a vague memory about this being possible but I cannot seem to formulate my question well enough for google / stack to give me an idea of what to do.

Given this code (transform function within a custom pipe -Angular 2-):

```
transform(statuses: Status[], test: string): Status[] {

    return statuses.filter(status => status.Id === 1);

    //Code to be executed after return has happened
    this.updatePager.emit();
  }
```

How do I get the code `this.updatePager.emit();`to happen right after my return statement.

Kind regards everyone. Tips on how to formulate this question so I can search further are always welcome!

Comment: `return` terminates the function.

Comment: you can not do anything after `return`. `setTimeout(func, 0)` could be the case to execute in the next tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you, execute code in the next application tick with `setTimeout 0`.

```
transform(statuses: Status[], test: string): Status[] {
    //Code to be executed in the next tick
    setTimeout( ()=> this.updatePager.emit(), 0 );

    return statuses.filter(status => status.Id === 1);
}
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. However , it feels dirty to me. What if , on the next tick the return statement hasn't finished yet? (I'm thinking about insanely long lists)

Comment: Since javascript generally run in a single thread, there are execution queue waiting for each timing tick. yes the `return` statement will finish before next tick, the `setTimeout 0` just push code into next tick execution queue.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
  transform(statuses: Status[], test: string): Status[] {

    setTimeout(function(){ this.updatePager.emit(); }, 1000); //Adjust time here.

    return statuses.filter(status => status.Id === 1);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

as  Nina Scholz said, return terminates the function. So you can execute the code with a delay using setTimeout:

```
transform(statuses: Status[], test: string): Status[] {
    setTimeout(() => {
        //Code to be executed after return has happened
        this.updatePager.emit();
    }, 500)

    return statuses.filter(status => status.Id === 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a [custom event and trigger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) the event before returning the function.